# Using .split() inside a .map() within a ajax's request wont work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to do a simple 24hour to 12hour time conversion on multiple times before storing that time in state, within a React.js app. For some reason I keep getting error:

```
Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

within my `.map()`

This is all within an ajax request (using axios) so I think it may have something to do with promises.

```
getData(){
    const dbURL = 'http://localhost:5984/db/_all_docs?include_docs=true'

    axios.get(dbURL).then((res)=>{
        //take care of time conversion
        let showings = res.data.rows
        let showingsData = [];
        let that = this;

        //create function to use in .map            
        function returnShowings(showings){

            let ampmTime = ""
            let time = showings.doc.time;
            let time_parts = time.split(":") 
            let ampm = ""

            if(time_parts[0] >= 12){
                ampm = "PM"
            }
            if(time_parts[0] > 12){
                time_parts[0] = time_parts[0] - 12;
            }

            ampmTime = time_parts[0] + ":" + time_parts[1] + ampm;

            let showingObj = {id: showings.doc._id, date: showings.doc.date, time: ampmTime}
            return showingObj;
        }

        //store all showing objects in an array
        showingsData = showings.map(returnShowings)

        //push showings to state 
        this.setState({showings: showingsData})

    });
}
```

I am then calling `getData()` within my `componentDidMount()`. This makes no sense I can `console.log(time.split(":")` right above or bellow where I actually call `.split` and it works no problem.

How can this possibly work within a `console.log()` but not within the function?

Comment: *"How can this possibly work within a console.log() but not within the function?"* - If it works within `console.log()` at the same point where you have `let time_parts = time.split(":")` then it *is* working within the function. Are you sure that every row has a `doc.time` property?

Comment: Mumble are you sure that the problem is not in some rows and not in others ? maybe you have tried to console.log() the first elements and the problem is in the others. Have you tried placing a debugger ? Also check the javascript (es5) version without source map maybe it's a transpilation problem

Comment: Ohhhh man, that was it!! I have a design doc in my couchDB database that I pop() off at a later time (its the very last record) so i guess console.log was showing me all the times for all the records, and my error was just for the very last record. But the ,map() just failes outright so no data was displayed. Thats why I thought it was a bigger error.
Thank you SOOO Much!! If you right out your answer ill mark it as correct. Cheers!